# Is perfboard generally lead-free?

Tags: safety, prototyping, protoboard, rohs

While shopping for perfboard/protoboard, the only products I've found listed as RoHS are brand-name items, costing several times that of the generics.

Is perfboard/protoboard inherently free of lead, etc?  Or should I pay up for the name-brand boards?  (I work on project with my children, hence my desire to avoid lead.)

Comment: As much as I admire your rhetoric, if you want to avoid lead, you are in the wrong hobby forum. Mind you, it's a lot better than it was a decade or two ago. Now we just need to work on all the other little toxic chemicals we work with...

Comment: For the cheap stuff, according to the smell, I would not be worried about the lead...

Comment: Why do you need a RoHS perfoboard? If it is for prototyping, it is probably legal. If it is for a product... Just don't. And if you are concerned about lead... Are you planning on soldering 40hrs per week for the next years?

Comment: I wouldn't be worried at all, you probably get more lead through the air you breath and the water you drink and the metal you touch than you would working with a perfboard *with lead in it*.

Comment: The fear mongers got to you?  Do not believe what you read or hear.  99% of the time it is bullshit.  Especially on Facebook or any site with the words organic, natural, or truth.  I played with mercury as a child, I regularly hold solder (not the lead free crap) in my mouth when soldering.  I'm 62 and doing fine.  Just how would lead get from a perf-board into the blood stream?  Those putting the RoHS labels are probably like the Gluten free on non gluten products or non-GMO labels on foods that have no GMO.  Perf boards probably do not an never did contain lead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the perfboard is tan colored with copper pads, there shouldn't be any lead there as perfboard is fiberglass and epoxy and if you can see copper pads, that's just copper. That is inherently lead-free.

On the other hand if you see a perfboard that is tan colored and has silver looking contact pads, and it isn't marketed as RoHS, then it likely has lead in it.

Overall, many things are inherently lead-free, they just haven't bothered to go through the RoHS certification process so they may not have a RoHS tag on them.